# access the data of a hook- React

Tags: json, reactjs, react-hooks

I am requesting this API, then I save the result in the "data" hook. when I want to print "data.total_results" everything ok but when I want to print a key that has more data inside it doesn't leave me "Data.results [0] .title"

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const Movie = () => {
  // Declara una nueva variable de estado, que llamaremos "count".
  const [Data, setData] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    const Cargar = async () => {
      let respuesta = await fetch("https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key=ce322f54257cc9286282b320c5e9b2a0&language=en-US&sort_by=popularity.desc&include_adult=false&include_video=false&page=1");
      let respuestaJSON = await respuesta.json();
      setData(respuestaJSON);
    };
    Cargar();
  }, [Data]);
  return (
    <div>
      {Data.total_results}
      {/* {Data.results[0].title} */}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Movie;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check if the `results` property is defined.

```
<div className="App">
  <h1>Total {Data.total_results}</h1>
  {typeof Data.results !== "undefined" &&
    Data.results.map((movie, index) => {
      return <h3>{movie.title}</h3>;
    })}
</div>
```

**Working Demo**: https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-feather-4l55r

A few days back, I have created a repository and implemented OMDB API with React. This may help you.

https://github.com/jogeshpi03/omdb-react

Comment: exactly this was what I needed

Answer (score 1):

Your code is almost right. There's a bug and a couple improvements you can make.

First let's take a look at the `useEffect` hook.

`useEffect` takes two arguments: a function, and a list of dependencies. The first time the component is rendered, and when any of the dependencies change, the function argument will be executed again.

So right now you have a bug with your dependencies that is causing an infinite loop. When the component is rendered, you execute the function in `useEffect`. That function will eventually set `Data`. When the value for `Data` is set, that will cause the `useEffect` function to be executed again. Which will set a new value to Data, which will execute the function again, ad infinitum.

The fix is to set the dependencies to `[]` if you only want that to run once. Like this:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const Cargar = async () => {
      let respuesta = await fetch("https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key=ce322f54257cc9286282b320c5e9b2a0&language=en-US&sort_by=popularity.desc&include_adult=false&include_video=false&page=1");
      let respuestaJSON = await respuesta.json();
      setData(respuestaJSON);
    };
    Cargar();
  }, []); // <-------- This changed to []
```

I hope that fixes your issue.

Now I will suggest some improvements:

I would set the initial state of `Data` to `undefined`

```
  const [Data, setData] = useState();
```

and then use a conditional in the JSX like so

```
if (!Data) {
  return <div>Loading...</div>
}

return (
  <div>
    {Data.total_results}
  </div>
);
```

Comment: Bravo!  I am surprised no one else really spotted the infinite loop. This is the basic concept of React hooks

Answer (score 0):

> **const [Data, setData] = useState([]);**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import ReactTable from 'react-table'
import 'react-table/react-table.css'
const Movie = () => {
  // Declara una nueva variable de estado, que llamaremos "count".

const [Data, setData] = useState([]);
   useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key=ce322f54257cc9286282b320c5e9b2a0&language=en-US&sort_by=popularity.desc&include_adult=false&include_video=false&page=1")
      .then(function(response) {
               console.log(response.data.results)
        setData(response.data.results);

      }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      })
  }, []);

  return (<div>
  {Data.map(function (row, i) {  
        return <div key={i}>
        {row.title} 
     </div>
   })}
 </div>)      
}

export default Movie;
```